# How to add a num to a string then return it?

Tags: c++

Here i was trying to add a number to a string then return it so i could use the function instead or writing that.

```
string add_num_to_str(string x, int z)
{
    x += to_string(z);
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    string text;
    int num;
    cout << "Your Text and Num:";
    cin >> text >> num;
    add_num_to_str(text, num);
    cout << "Your Text and Num are: " << text;
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: What does "add a num to a string" mean? How do you want to add? And why do you return `1` when a `std::string` is the return type?

Comment: I really don't know but i'm a begginer with AMXX-Pawn experience and confuses me a little.

Comment: Try `return x;`

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work idk why. It s like the number isn't added or that the function doesn't work, maybe i did something wrong while testing it?

Comment: Write an example for the input ( the string and the integer)

Comment: La 10 and returns me only La

Comment: `text = add_num_to_str(text, num);`

Comment: Your  current code ignores the return value / throws it away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add_num_to_str()` function is fine. Your `main()` code is simply ignoring the new string that is being returned.

You need to change this:

`add_num_to_str(text, num);`

To this:

`text = add_num_to_str(text, num);`

C++17 and later have a [`nodiscard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) attribute that would prevent you from being able to make this mistake:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] string add_num_to_str(string x, int z)
{
    x += to_string(z);
    return x;
}
```

The alternative is to change your function to take the string by reference and modify it in place:

```cpp
void add_num_to_str(string& x, int z)
{
    x += to_string(z);
}

int main()
{
    string text;
    int num;
    cout << "Your Text and Num:";
    cin >> text >> num;
    add_num_to_str(text, num);
    cout << "Your Text and Num are: " << text;
    return 0;
}
```